# Why does var_dump output "Generator", although die is called before yield?

Tags: php, iterator

I was wondering, why the output is `"object(Generator)#2 (0) { }"` and not something like `string(3) "foo"`.
I just used this piece of code to test the behaviour.

```php
<?php

class Foo
{
    protected function baz() {
        $array = [
            'a' => 'a1',
            'b' => 'b1',
            'c' => 'c1',
            'd' => 'd1',
        ];
        
        die('foo');
        
        foreach($array as $foo) {
            yield $array;
        }
    }
    
    public function bar() {
        var_dump($this->baz());
    }
}

(new Foo())->bar();
```

**EDIT**: I tried it with PHP 7.1, 7.2, 7.4, 8.0 and 8.2. The behaviour remains the same.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php): "A generator function looks just like a normal function, except that instead of returning a value, a generator yields as many values as it needs to. Any function containing yield is a generator function." So your `die` gets wrapped in the generator and doesn't run until invoked.

Comment: The generator function isn't called until you try to iterate over it, e.g. `foreach ($this->baz() as $item)`

Comment: But even, if I put a `return $array` before the `foreach` loop it is evaluated as a generator function. How is that possible? Because then the `yield` will never be reached.